# Cannot enable ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

As per the instructions, I downloaded ABS 4.1, created a new project from existing sources in the library/ folder. As soon as I do that, a few errors pop up in the log:

```
[2012-10-02 10:47:30 - library] Unable to resolve target 'android-14'
```

Along with a huge number of errors:

```
[2012-10-02 10:34:40 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\****\Documents\Code\Eclipse\Ferric\AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

From what I can guess it is because I have not set the correct target SDK version. Hopw am I supposed to this in a library?

Comment: check your manifest file first.

Comment: Search StackOverflow. This question has been answered

Comment: I found a few similar ones - could you point me to the correct one please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, Project -> Properties -> Android and check Android 4.0 or higher.

Comment: That still does not work. Doing that removes all the problems from the Android Console, but Problems shows me 100 errors and 3 warnings.

Comment: Update: changed Java build target to 1.6, all problems fixed. :D